# check power spectrum

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum

my question is quite straight-forward to be grasped and handled.

I have an 1D array, `F_11` representing a target power spectrum. It is sketched in the following figure

[image]

Then, I start generating a time series `u` which embodies the properties of `F_11`, as follows

```
nn = complex(normrnd(0,1,[1,1000]),normrnd(0,1,[1,1000]));
u = abs(fftn(fftshift(F_11.*nn)));
```

Finally, just to check that u does actually reproduce a spectrum as `F_11`, I try going backwards as follows

```
ps =  abs(ifftn(ifftshift(u)));
```

But, when plotting `ps`, it does not exactly match `F_11`

[image]

In the high frequency area, `ps` drifts upwards, which is quite weird.

Would you mind to sketch the flaw in my procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `u` variable is just the magnitude of the FFT, not the actual complex numbers that represent the FFT. Try removing the `abs()` from `u` and then doing the IFFT.

Comment: Do you mean calling `u = (fftn(fftshift(F_11.*nn)));` and `ps =  abs(ifftn(ifftshift(u)));`?

Comment: Yes. You can keep `u` in its complex number form and then call `abs()` or `angle()` on it before plotting depending on if you want to see the magnitude or the phase of the FFT.

Comment: But I wanna recover the power spectrum. I have no interest in evaluating amplitudes and phase. Perhaps the issue comes from using fft instead of 1D fft

Comment: The power spectrum is the magnitude squared of the FFT. Normally I would take a time signal `x` and have `X=fft(x)`, then `ps=abs(X).^2=X*X'`, but to get back to `x` I would do `x=ifft(X)` not `x=ifft(ps)`
I don't think your `u` is a time series.

Answer (score 0):

Can you first generate white noise and then filter it with the power spectrum that you desire? You can generate white Gaussian noise using `wgn`[1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/wgn.html).